# css inline block with fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn designing a website.

1. Is there any way I can set my whole page width to `1000px` with the current responsive sticky footer I have?
2. If possible, on top of the condition mentioned above, I want the left and right div to be horizontally align and the div will become vertical align when the screen collapse.

Here is my html/css code:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3hMH/)

Comment: For question 1, yes.  You already have a wrapper class, try setting the width there.  Don't forget that you can center block level content (like a div) that has width applied to it by setting its left and right margins to auto.  For question 2, the css property float is what you'll need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-width:1000px;` to the `.wrapper` class and make the `.content` class `float:left`

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    height: auto; 
    max-width:1000px; /*add this line*/
}

.content {
    background-color: slateblue;
    width: 500px;
    float:left; /*add this line*/
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2ZW/

Comment: thanks for the reply! I just have little questions, when I expand the result box, the footer background grey color expand with the box, how do I solve this? and is it possible to do it without float?

Comment: @Andrew, you could make the `body` be `max-width:1000px` instead of the `.wrapper`. This way it will affect the `.footer` as well. For the `float:left` you can do it with `display:inline-block` ***but*** you must make sure that there is no whitespace between the two `div` elements. **Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2ZW/2/**

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! I remember reading somewhere that a link break or <br> will cost a whitespace...although Im not sure about that

Comment: yes, line breaks in the source code are white space (and because you set the two divs as `display:inline-block` the whitespace between them gets rendered as any other whitespace..

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/S3hMH/1/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
}

.content {
    background-color: slateblue;
    width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2ZW/1/)

If you are relatively new to responsive design i suggest using a framework as

[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Coming to your questions.

1. Ya You can set your page-width to 1000px.

   ```
   #wrapper{
   margin: 0 auto;
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 1000px;
   }

   .content{
   width: 50%;
   float:left;
   }
   ```

   `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .content{
         width:100%;
           }
      }`

Content will occupy 100% width and stacks horizontally if the screen resolution is less than 480px because of the query above.Using % width helps you when designing responsive web pages

Comment: Sorry Gaby got it first....
I have thought about using a framework which I did before using html5up, but I totally don't know where to start re-designing.So, I ended up starting my own idea...

Comment: @Andrew If you are building responsive web page go with media queries